# Disabled TLS but SSL online analyzer finds it as enabled. Why?

Tags: ssl, https, apache2.4

In my virtual host I specified to disable TLSv1 and TLSv1.1

```
SSLProtocol                      all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite                   ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256

SSLHonorCipherOrder              on
SSLCompression                   off
SSLSessionTickets                off

# OCSP Stapling, only in httpd 2.3.3 and later
SSLUseStapling                   on
SSLStaplingResponderTimeout      5
SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off
SSLStaplingCache                 shmcb:/var/run/ocsp(128000)
```

Then I tested using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.htm

Buy I anyway continue to see

```
Protocols
TLS 1.3 No
TLS 1.2 Yes
TLS 1.1 Yes
TLS 1.0 Yes
SSL 3   No
SSL 2   No
For TLS 1.3 tests, we only support RFC 8446.
```

I restarted both apache2 and sshd before re-run the analizer, but nothing changes.

What am I missing?

EDIT: it's a new VM with debian 9, apache 2 and certbot, with only one virtual host, and I also disabled the default one.

Probably some config in *other files* are conflicting or overriding my settings, so I'll investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons for this, like

- You don't actually test your server configuration. This can happen if there is a SSL terminating load balancer or reverse proxy in front of your server or if your server is behind a CDN (Cloudflare, Akamai, ...).
- You have multiple virtual hosts on the same IP address and port with different configurations regarding the SSLProtocol. Only one of the settings will be actually used in this case and it might not be the one you expected.
- You have different configurations for IPv4 and IPv6 and made the changes only to one of these configuration.
- You made the changes to parts of the configuration which take no effect.

Comment: So the problem is NOT in this posted configuration, but in something other that is conflicting or overriding, right? I'll investigate. It'a a new VM with a fresh install of apache2, and only a virtual host, but I remember that by default there are othere SSL-related settings in some files. Thanks for reply (I cannot understand downvote like every other time .. .. but amen...)

Answer (score 0):

Like state in accepted answer, the was some conflicting settings.

In my VHost config I was including

```
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
```

And I setup *my settings* outside the vhost. So my settings take less precedence than included one.

And included one WAS NOT disabling TLSv1, for example.

Fixed the included file, all works as expected.

Thanks again [@Steffen Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich)